# Telnet enable linemode from server

Tags: c, linux, networking, gnu, telnet

I am working on a line-oriented telnet server, not a client.

Currently, to set up the connection, I am using:

```
IAC DONT ECHO
IAC DONT SURPRESS-GO-AHEAD
IAC DO LINEMODE
IAC DO NAWS
```

Currently, the server only handles IAC AYT, and NAWS-related stuff. Anything else is rejected, like so:

```
IAC DONT <OPTION>
```

However, the server still gets characters one-at-a-time.

According to [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231866), ECHO and SGA (at the same time) enable character-at-a-time mode. However, I have both disabled.
How can I make the client send data one line at a time?

I am using the telnet from GNU inetutils to test this.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093057/telnet-server-enable-client-linemode)'s title is similar but, contrary to its title, concerns writing a telnet client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just checked my old telnet server source and I send WILL and WONT from the server side. I handled DO and DONT from the client.

Are you actually trying to code a true telnet server, or just a server that is compatible with telnet that does sends data a line at a time (like a text based chat or game server)? If the latter, you can do away with most of your options because in my experience, telnet clients default to line at a time.

For my game server (MUD++) all I ever did in standard game play mode was to disable / enable echo during password state in login, or kick into character mode and start a pseudo tty when the user invoked the PICO editor.

UPDATE: If you plan to seriously write a telnet server or any other network software, I really like the classic W. Richard Stevens series. ***TCP/IP Illustrated Volume 1, The Protocols*** covers telnet in a practical sense, and coupled with the RFCs like 1184 (if I recall) you'll have everything you need.

Comment: It doesn't work. I still get the characters one-at-a-time. GNU inetutils seems to send IAC WONT ECHO. Is GNU inetutils the cause?

Comment: I assume it is sending WONT ECHO because your server sends DONT ECHO and WONT is the response to DONT.

Comment: @theunamedguy:  If it's sending "WONT ECHO" in response to you telling it "DONT ECHO", then that would be normal.  It might help if you put the entire message exchange in your original post.

Comment: Never mind. I had some stale code sitting around that enabled SGA. It works with it removed.

Comment: Oh yeah, this wasn't a "real" telnet server, it's just a game server

Comment: In that case, you can keep the telnet negotiation to the minimum as some clients wont support them anyway. Most clients support echo on/off at least, and if I recall, some of them did not support full screen / character mode. People used mudmaster and tintin++ to play mine a lot, but that was 20 years ago, so I'm way out of date.